# Mechanize upload binary data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanize

My rails app is hosted by heroku

I have my file in the database as binary data. i want to upload the file using mechanize

i want to be able to upload using mechanize directly without saving to disk

how do i do this ?

I'm thinking something like stringio but don't know

any help is much appreciated.

Arun

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this

form.file_uploads[0].file_data = voucher
form.file_uploads[0].file_name = "voucher.jpg"

Arun